# Issue with iterating through R data.table trying to call a function

Tags: r, data.table

Long time reader first time submitter. I'm relatively new to R and I'm in the middle of a project trying to complete a significant portion that was due today :).

I'm trying to iterate through a data.table and apply a function to each row of the data.table. What is bizarre to me is that I can pass each value individually and it works but when I try iterate with lapply et. al. or a for loop I can't get the function to work. I've tried to include as much information code etc. as I can. I apologize for the length.

data.table containing the donor information. I've obscured the donor_id.

```
> str(testdonors)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  22 obs. of  34 variables:
 $ donor_id          : Factor w/ 455 levels "XXYYWWW","WWWXXYY",..: 281 282 283 284 285 286 289 290 291 292 ...
 $ Date_of_Death     : POSIXct, format: "2012-01-03" "2012-01-03" "2012-01-02" "2012-01-02" ...
 $ rec_out_us        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ age               : num  20.1 22.9 54.3 28.7 43.4 ...
 $ gender            : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ race              : Factor w/ 4 levels "Black","Hispanic",..: 4 4 4 2 4 2 4 3 4 2 ...
 $ cause_death       : Factor w/ 4 levels "Anoxia","Other Cause",..: 1 4 3 3 1 3 3 4 3 4 ...
 $ circum_death      : Factor w/ 5 levels "Homicide","Natural",..: 4 5 2 2 3 2 2 1 2 5 ...
 $ method_death      : Factor w/ 7 levels "Asphyxiation",..: 1 5 7 7 6 7 7 4 7 5 ...
 $ blood_type        : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","AB","B","O": 4 4 1 4 1 4 4 2 1 4 ...
 $ bmi               : num  20.4 19.6 24.9 27.4 25.7 ...
 $ serum_creat       : num  0.69 1.8 0.64 0.81 0.7 1.31 2.67 0.6 0.57 0.95 ...
 $ hb_core_anti      : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hb_surface_anti   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hc_anti           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cis_blood         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cis_lung          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cis_urine         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cis_other         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ dcd_non_hb        : int  0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ dcd_controlled    : int  0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ca_after_bd       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ lung_p02          : num  117 63 143 104 379 ...
 $ cigarette_use     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cigarette_use_6mos: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cocaine_use       : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ cocaine_use_6mos  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ drug_use_other    : int  1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ heavy_alcohol     : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ high_risk_donor   : int  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ history_diabetes  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ insulin_dep       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ history_hypten    : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ history_cancer    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "donor_id"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Function 1

```
calc_donor_yield <- function(p_model_id, p_donor){
  heart_yield <- calc_heart_yield(p_model_id, p_donor)
  ...
}
```

Function 2

```
calc_heart_yield <- function(p_model_id, p_donor){

  if(p_donor[, hb_core_anti == 1 || hb_surface_anti == 1 || hc_anti == 1]){
    heart_yield = 0.0036
  } else {
    heart_yield <- get_organ_yield(p_model_id,"heart_coeff",p_donor)
  }

  heart_yield
}
```

This works!
test1 <- calc_donor_yield(1,testdonors[2,])

These don't...

```
lapply(testdonors["donor_id",], function(x) calc_donor_yield(1,x))
Error in NextMethod("[") : object 'hb_core_anti' not found
Called from: (function () 
{
    .rs.breakOnError(TRUE)
})()

lapply(testdonors[list(donor_id),],function(donor) calc_donor_yield(1,donor)) 

Error in NextMethod("[") : object 'hb_core_anti' not found
Called from: (function () 
{
    .rs.breakOnError(TRUE)
})()
```

In both of these calls it looks like p_donor is just the first element of the data.table.

I've also tried a for loop

```
results <- for (n in 1:nrow(testdonors)) calc_donor_yield(1,testdonors[donorIDlist[n]])
```

returns NULL

Thanks for any help on this. Please let me know if there's any additional detail required to help get this answered.

Comment: I'm guessing at what calc_heart_yield is intended to do -- I think perhaps the problem is `p_donor[, hb_core_anti == 1 || hb_surface_anti == 1 || hc_anti == 1]` (which would give you all rows and either column 0 or 1, depending on the values of current-environment variables hb_etc, of p_donor) is a very different expression from e.g. `p_donor$hb_core_anti == 1 || p_donor$hb_surface_anti == 1 || p_donor$hc_anti == 1` (which may still be indexed wrong; I'm not sure if you get a list or a 1-row data.frame inside lapply. This is list syntax). Did you intend something like the latter?

Comment: I generally find that preparing a small dataset with the needed complexity and working with it often lets the problem become clearer. At the moment you have a bunch of functions that are undefined and data that we can only guess at. This looks like you are passing a single row with lapply: `testdonors["donor_id",]`. Generally one would expect to pass a column.

Answer (score 0):

Or simple command

```
test1 <- calc_donor_yield(1,testdonors[2,])
```

works because you are passing in one row of a data.table/data.frame which itself is a data.table.

When you call

```
lapply(testdonors["donor_id",], function(x) calc_donor_yield(1,x))
```

I think you intended to get the donor_id column, not the row named "donor_id", so that really should be be

```
lapply(testdonors[,"donor_id"], function(x) calc_donor_yield(1,x))
```

which is only passing the value of the donor_id column into the x value, not the entire row of the data.frame.

I believe your loop idea is the closest but you have the indexing incorrect and you can't assign the results that way. How about

```
results<- lapply(1:nrow(testdonors), function(n) {
    calc_donor_yield(1,testdonors[n,])
})
```

Here you would be passing in a row index as `calc_donor_yield(1,testdonors[n,])` just as you did in your simple example `calc_donor_yield(1,testdonors[2,])`