# Iterating over data.table in lapply or for loop

Tags: r, data.table

I basically am wondering why it makes a difference if you iterate over a vector created from a data.table or over a basic vector and why that is the case.
I think basically it's quite similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434717/issue-with-iterating-through-r-data-table-trying-to-call-a-function), but I can narrow it down to a more basic example.

```
 dt <- setDT(structure(list(File.Name = c("file1.xlsx", "file2.xlsx", "file3.xlsx")
 , Split.ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L)
 , .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11","12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), class = "factor"))
 , .Names = c("File.Name", "Split.ID")
 , class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L)))


 for(file in as.vector(dt[1:3,1])){
    print(file)
    }

  for(i in letters[1:4]){print(i)}
```

As can be seen from the output, in the first for-loop it just prints out all values in the first iteration and in the second loop it loops over the distinct letters.

I am trying to use the file names in connection with readxl, so vectorizing the function is not really an option, since I want to do it sequentially. Additionally I would like to keep the list of files as an data.table to be able to split in different parts.

Comment: Short answer: use `unlist` instead of `as.vector`. Note that `str(c(as.vector(dt[1:3,1])))`  shows that the returned object is a list of length 1. From the help file, `?as.vector` "attempts to coerce its argument into a vector of mode mode."  Since data.tables are lists, then `as.vector` will return a list when applied to a data.table. You can see this with `mode(dt)`, which returns "list".

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's quite funny, that in case of `lapply` this then means that you explicitly have to use `unlist` although you should provide a `list`. :-)

Comment: Well... `lapply` takes either a list or a vector, and returns a list. Better ways to extract a variable as a vector from dt is to use `$` or `[[`.

Comment: To clarify lmo's last suggestion, all of these work: `dt[1:3, File.Name]`, `dt[["File.Name"]][1:3]`, `dt[[1]][1:3]`, `dt$File.Name[1:3]`. Btw, if you type `vignette("datatable-faq")`, you'll see the first couple questions cover this stuff.

Comment: I always thought, that `dt[1:3, File.Name]` and in this case `dt[1:3, 1]` are perfect substitutes.